# how to SSH Login Without Password

Tags: ssh, ksh, ssh-keys

To use sftp in a script without user interaction (non-interactive). For example to login to an anonymous ftp server and not have to manually.

Comment: Do you have access to your server?, because you will need to edit the configuration file. So it will allow Anonymous connections. Correct me if i am wrong. Hope this helps. Wesley.

Comment: Are you asking about SSH, or FTP? The question title and question body seem to be in conflict...

Comment: A 4 minute video tutorial is here -

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGwk6zM_NDM

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**On your computer**

```
cd ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

press the enter key at every prompt

```
Generating public/private dsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_dsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
ad:98:43:13:c9:ea:66:8e:d0:d9:66:59:d8:3a:f7:29
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ DSA 1024]----+
|                 |
|     . .         |
|      +          |
|     + . .       |
|    o = S .      |
| . + = + .       |
|. o @ = .        |
| . B oEo .       |
|  . .  .o        |
+-----------------+
```

you will get 2 files `id_dsa` and `id_dsa.pub` use scp or other utility to copy file to your server

```
scp ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub user@host:~/.ssh/
```

**On your server**

Add the new key to the file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Finally change the access modes;

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

Verify that access mode is correct for ~

```
ls -ld ~
```

if not, you can use

```
chmod 700 ~
```

to correct your home access.

Logout and login again

Comment: @E.G: is it necessary that files are dsa, not rsa?

Comment: @gaussblurinc In my cause only works with **RSA**

Comment: OpenSSH [deprecated DSA keys](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/112802/why-openssh-deprecated-dsa-keys) last year. Use RSA keys unless you have a specific reason not to. The RSA key filenames will normally be *id_rsa* and *id_rsa.pub*.

Answer (score 15):

Type the following commands

1. `ssh-keygen`

   Press Enter key till you get the prompt
2. `ssh-copy-id -i root@ip_address`

   (It will once ask for the password of the host system)
3. `ssh root@ip_address`

   Now you should be able to login without any password

Answer (score 3):

To allow ssh login without entering a password at each login, append your public ssh key to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on your target server. You can find your public key in ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub or, if it doesn't exist, you may need to generate one.

See detailed answer [here](http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html)

Comment: Please summarize the steps and don't just post links.

Answer (score 0):

May be if you want to turn off SFTP asking you YES/NO questions for each transfer of file when doing ftp using a ftp script file you can use `-n -i` command line arguments.

```
    ftpscript.in
-----------------
user username pwd
get sourcefile targetfileonlocal
bye
```

Then you can run this script using `ftp -n -i servername<ftpscript.in` to avoid getting "Do you want to transfer the sourcefile?y/n" kind of questions. For logging into ftp server without user name, password then the server ftp needs to allow anonymous logins as mentioned by Wesley.