# How to add a passphrase into a script for a scp command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script which should simply copy some file from Server A to Server B. To be able to do so, during the script is running I am asked to manually type the Passphrase. My question is how can I automate that, so the Passphrase is automatically added?

```sh
scp -i ${SCPKEY} ${SCPFILETOCOPY} ${SCPUSER}@${SCPDEST}
```

this is an example of the command I use in the script

I couldn't find any solution on the web. I tried using the `sshpass` but it did not work...

The Problem is basically with the 2 side authentication.

Thank you in advance for all your help!

Comment: Key based authentication should be used for this, if possible. Else you can use `expect` .

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388385/how-to-ssh-login-without-password

Answer (score 2):

Provided you are using public-private key pair authentication (looking at the command you listed), then you have 2 options:

1. (Recommended security-wise): use  `ssh-agent` before using your script, this way you will have to supply the key pair password just once in your interactive session. As long as the session is open, your script will run without asking for the key passphrase.

```
$ ssh-agent bash
$ ssh-add
```

Then run your script.
2. (Not recommended security-wise) Save your private key unencrypted, i.e without the passphrase, then your script will work even NOT in interactive terminal session. The downside is of course anyone who can read your dir on the server can steal the private key.

Comment: thx for your help, it's interessting that using the agent the script runs one time without error but then i get permission denied as a response from the recieve-server... and when I check the list in the agent with the command: ssh-add -l i get
"Could not open a connection to your authentication agent"... strange...

Comment: Most probably your script upon finishing does logout via `exit/break` from loop etc. and this closes the shell session opened with `ssh-agent bash` basically closing the ssh-agent

Comment: isn't it ```$ ssh-add keyfile``` instead of  ```$ ssh-agent add```  ?